# CSS - Cannot get one spanned style to override another inherited style and align left

Tags: css, class, overriding

I have a `div` classed content.

Inside the `div`, is a `h1` tag.

Inside the `h1` tag is a `span` tag, with its' class set to regTalker.

Here is the tag:

```
<h1><span class="regTalker">Not Listed? Register <a href="?register">here</a></span>Browse Listings</h1>
```

The regTalker class looks like this:

```
.regTalker {
    text-align: left !important;
    font-family: GoodDog;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    color: #000;
}
```

The container `div` has `text-align` value set to center.

The main string inside of the `h1` tag displays centered.

The string inside of the `span` tag is also centered, not aligned to the left, as i would presume it to be...

What gives? Surely `!important` should override the content `div` `text-align` value?

There are two different css files in question, the main one, and the seconary one, which houses the regTalker class... These files are linked one after each other, so incase this comes up in an answer, it is not due to the instance of inclusion.

I have also cleared my cache and reloaded the css file directly. So its not that either.

I am using firefox 8.0.1, have not tried it on other browsers yet.

If anyone has any advice, or input regarding this issue, or how to solve the problem, it would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can you please include the HTML and CSS instead of describing it?

Comment: It probably should be noted that using `!important` is generally considered less than best practice.

Comment: @idrumgood, have now added the html, css was already there?

Comment: @Nathan Arthur, that said, would you be able to provide a better solution for this? My original one was a float, but it caused countless issues with alignment when resizing the window or changing resolutions.

Comment: I don't think span can have `text-align` that's really seen because they are not block elements. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756926/difference-between-span-and-div-with-text-aligncenter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text-align applies to the content of the element it's applied to, not the element itself.  The text inside the span is left-aligned, but the span itself is centre-aligned within its parent.  As the span is an inline level element, it's only ever as wide as its content and as the span is centre aligned, its content will also appear to be centre-aligned...

If the span was as wide as its container, then the text in it would appear left-aligned, but you have to apply a `display: block` or `display: inline-block` to it before you can assign it a width.

Also, never use !important.  It'll just lead to tears and gnashing of teeth in the long run.

Comment: okay i have changed done the above chances to the regTalker class. If i change it to block, it displayed above the h1 tag, aligned to the left. If i choose inline-block, i have the same problem as before. If i then add a width of 100% i go back to the same problem as when i chose block? Any ideas?

Comment: It's hard to be sure what you want without a diagram showing the desired effect, or the containing div in the markup, but if I understand you right, then what you really might want is for the span to float to the left.  From the sound of it your design running up against what's called the document flow.  Floating the span left will take it out of the flow and float it to the leftmost edge of the containing div.

Comment: Basically what happens, is that if i float it left, the main text in the h1 tag is pushed to the right, and is no longer dead center of the page... What i am trying to achieve, is have that string stay dead center, with the addittional text within the span, to be aligned left, without affecting the main text.

Comment: The page is always 100% of the screen width, so simply positioning it `left: 100px;` does not keep a fluid effect.

Comment: It might be worthwhile saying that the same is true for 100%. And that i have tried to counter the main text from being pushed to the right, by adding `left: -5%;` But this also, does not keep a fluid effect.

Answer (score 2):

You're slightly misunderstanding how `text-align` works.  You can't use `text-align` to change the alignment of a `span` within its container; `text-align` affects the *contents* of the element it's applied to, and cannot affect its *context*.  (If your span were a block element, your declaration would make its contents align left *within it*, but would still not make the span itself align left within its container.)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this to answer the problem most described in comments for the answer from GordonM:

```
.regTalker {
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
    left: -20%;
    margin-right: -10%;
    font-family: GoodDog;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    color: #000;
}
```

This was used to keep the main text within the `h1` tag roughly centered, while applying positioning to the `span` element within it.