# CSS right align rule not working

Tags: html, css

I have created a CSS rule to align the text to the right. But when I am imposing that rule on a font in a cell, it is not aligning it to the right! Can anybody tell why???

Here is my code:

CSS:

```
.font1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: right;
```

HTML:

```
<table width="90%" align="center" bgcolor="#669999" border="10" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td style="border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px; font-family: Nyala; font-size: 80px; color: #000;"><p><span class="font1">Name1<br />
        </span>
        Name2</p>

      </p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td width="300" align="center" style="vertical-align:top;border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px"><img src="pictures/logo - without bg.png" width="200" height="200" alt="logo-without bg" /></td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please share your code and if possible then reproduce it on jsfiddle

Comment: done. please check now.

Comment: What text should be right aligned? FYI you have two closing </p> tags but only one opening one.

Comment: Text to right align: 'Name1'

Comment: removed the extra </p>, still no help...

Comment: How about 'Name2'? left or right? will Name1 and Name 2 be on the same line or separate lines?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between <span> and <div> with text-align:center;?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756926/difference-between-span-and-div-with-text-aligncenter)

Answer (score 23):

Text alignment only works with a block-level element. Block level elements occupy a maximum width within their box layout, so there's potentially space in which to align text to the left, center, or right.

A span tag is inline, unless you explicitly set the display to block. Inline elements take the minimum space possible to wrap their contents. So, it doesn't make sense to left, center, or right align text within that space -- the space is exactly the size of the content, so there's no room for alignment.

The better way to align the text in this particular case is to use the block level element that is available, the TD:

```
<td style="text-align: right;"> ... </td>
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/G3mhw/

Alternative, you can apply `display:block` to turn the span into a block level element:

```
.font1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: right; 
    display:block;
}
```

See it: http://jsfiddle.net/G3mhw/1/

**Related reading**

- *Block-level elements* on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements
- *Block-level vs. Inline Elements* on About.com - http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/block_vs_inline_elements.htm

Comment: In my case: I had quotes around the value 'right' in my style while using a class to assign the style. With the quotes, firefox did not align right. Without the quotes it worked. Odd rookie error but easy to fix.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that the `<span>` element is an `inline` element and therefore gets it's width from the contents inside it. This means the span is only as wide as it's contents and therefore, you see no changes when you add the `text-align` property.

Here is a good answer for reference on this: [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756926/difference-between-span-and-div-with-text-aligncenter#answer-7757048)

`text-align` will only show in `block` level elements. To solve your problem, you can either align the text in the `<td>` element or add `display: block` to your `<span>` CSS.

Answer (score 4):

Span tags do not have display: block by default, so the text-align will not have an effect since the span tag will just occupy the width of its contents.

So you could try changing the span tag to a div tag, and add the css element of width.

Or add display: block; to css font1 for the span tag and add a width:

Example:

```
.font1 {
    .font-size: 60px;
    .width: 100%;
    .display: block;
    .text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked when I added width /*eyeroll*