# div text align center issues inside loop

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a div with `text-align:center`.

Inside the div I have a `span`.

In the fiddle you can see the output 1,2 3, etc.

It is `float:left`, so I get the output it in one line.

But inside the div it is not obeying the style, `text-align:center`.
If I remove float left, the outputs will be in different lines but the text will be aligned center.

I need all my output in one line and it should aligned to the center of the `div`.

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.col = ['1', '2', '5', '8'];
  $scope.cols = ['1', '2', '5', '8'];
}
```

```css
.ll {
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="c in size">
  <span ng-repeat="m in p.size" ng-if="m == c.id">
    <a href="" ng-click="select_size(c.id)" 
       ng-class="{gvborder : allsels == c.id}">
       <p style="text-align:center; float:left"> {{c.name}} &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

My fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8odujjwm/)

Comment: Your question is very vague and your fiddle doesn't explain what exactly you wish to center.
However, this might be help you: http://howtocenterincss.com/

Comment: which text in fiddle you want to center?

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: I don't see any elements with `text-align:center;` in your example

Comment: You need to include the relevant code in your question, not as a link to an external resource.  Links go dead, and SO questions live a very long time to help aid people that may have the same question later.  Please include the code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set your `<span>` to `display:block` before doing `text-align:center;` since `<span>` is `display: inline` by default.

[Here's another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756926/difference-between-span-and-div-with-text-aligncenter) that goes into more detail about this topic.